# Почему не срабатывает preg_replace

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$str = '[p1=>1][p2=>2][p3=>3][p4=>4]';
$str = preg_replace('\[p2=>\w+[a-zA-Z0-9_]]','[p2=>333]', $str);
echo $str;
```

Подскажите, почему не происходит замена?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, нет крайних символов, определяющих регулярное выражение.
Во-вторых, квадратные скобки экранировать надо, это же не символьный класс.
В-третьих, зачем `\w`?

```
<?
$str = '[p1=>1][p2=>2][p3=>3][p4=>4]';
$str = preg_replace('!\[p2=>[a-z0-9_]\]!i','[p2=>333]', $str);
print $str;
```

Comment: @Флекс, обращайся!

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\[p2=>\d+\]/','[p2=>333]', $str);
```

Comment: Нельзя, по регулярке видно, что он планирует не только цифры туда ставить.

Comment: В строке видно, что там только цифры. Экстрасенсы в отпуске, чтобы предсказывать, что он туда планирует ставить.

Comment: Не надо быть экстрасенсом, чтобы догадаться, что он написал в регулярке, а там попытка впрячь ещё и алфавит с нижним пробелом.

Comment: @TheDoctor, совсем не факт, т.к. регулярка могла быть скопирована откуда-то не особо задумываясь о том, как оно работает, просто подогнали интуитивно шаблон и всё. Всякое бывает. 

@Флекс, можно использовать онлайн отладчики, например вот [этот][1]. Там и подсказки есть и описание и сразу видим результат выполнения.

  [1]: https://regex101.com/

Comment: @Isaev, в любом случае - ТС ничего не говорил по этому поводу, но принял мой ответ, значит...